# How can I optimize this Dwarven Inquisitor build for effectiveness of overrun attack and intimidate strategies?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, pathfinder-society

*I am creating a character that should follow all the Pathfinder Society's rules.* The character will not go to level 20 ( I think 14-16 will be his cap ).

Currently I have this overall picture:

**Race:** 
Dwarf (Darkvision; Weapon Familiarity; Defensive Training; Unstoppable; Relentless ; Industrious Urbanit; Rock Stepper)

**Class:**
Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer) 1

**Stats:**
  STR 16; DEX 12; CON 16; INT 8; WIS 16; CHA 8;

**Traits:** 
  Fate's Favored. Magical Knack(Inquisitor)

**Feats:**
  Toughness(bonus from alternate racial trait), Lightning Reflexes (can still be changed, I simply didn't find anything fitting - everything I wanted required BAB +1)

### The concept

A wandering dwarven inquisitor of Abadar, god of civilization, pursuing the profession of merchant and using Travel domain to strike fear into brigands who prey on the people using the roads. Using the racial trait Relentless, as well as an additional speed granted by Travel domain, I want to build a charger who tramples the opposition with a two-handed weapon. And the ones who remain standing shall quake in fear.

This inquisitor needs a quickest way to get Heavy Armor and martial weapons, so I am planning to dip Fighter on level 2. I have considered vanilla and all archetypes, and narrowed it down to Lore Warden, Siegebreaker and Unbreakable. Siegebreaker seems to give me the best overrun-centered options and doesn't trade out weapon or armor.

For an Inquisitor, I am trading out Judgements for some Slayer abilities with an archetypes. Getting a Sneak Attack for a heavily armored character is counter-intuitive, but I think it could work with just flanking. Gaining Greater Overrun would allow for free attacks versus enemies I overrun, ways to add sneak attack dies to that could be cool.

Gaining a couple of slayer talents could also be good, and I am considering Slowing Strike, grabbing a feat from Ranger's Two-Handed Weapon combat style(the 6th and 10th level ones become available), and Bleeding Attack or Surprise Attack from rogue talents. Just Weapon Training or Combat Trick could be gained there as well.

The Intimidate bonus from Stern Gaze on Inquisitor is nice and flavorful, so I was looking for ways to weaponize that as well through Dazzling Display or Bludgeoner + Enforcer + Intimidating Prowess. But intimidate goes after the tankiness in priority.

The order of taking the feats and slayer talents is of yet unclear (except Power Attack on 3, of course), and I think I can afford one more level of dip somewhere.

**What should I do to optimize the effectiveness of this build at each level?**

Comment: As you are planning on having intimidate being part of your build, and for sharing your stats in general it would be helpful if you also gave us your charisma score.

Comment: Are you willing to change your level 1 feat? Lightning Reflexes isn't a great way to get into Overrunning and Intimidating enemies. Useful, to be sure, but not the best start.

Comment: @DanielWilliams, yes, sorry. CHA is 8 - maybe unfitting for an intimidator, but I hoped to rely on Stern Gaze .

Comment: @Ifusaso, yes, it's variable. Didn't find anything fitting - everything I stumbled on kinda depended on +1 BAB, so I just took something "generally nice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- Skills: you'll probably want to rush Intimidate but max it at 5-10, based on preference since you only get 1 skill point for fighter levels, 5 for Inquisitor levels.
- Ranger combat style Slayer Talents do not work for you because the class feature requires that you be wearing no, light, or medium armor. For this reason I recommend simply rogue talent- combat trick. You'll never get a 2nd because it requires 16 Inquisitor levels (for some terrible reason).
- Your stated goal of being a tank and running around, provoking attacks of opportunity with a 2H weapon and Power Attack (not Combat Expertise), dealing sneak attack damage are a little at odds. Your itemization will have to be a little more tactical toward defensive items; magic armor is cheaper than magic weapons anyway.
- If you like the idea about being a more tactical/skilled fighter who uses brute force more because it's a good strategy (not all he's good at), swap out Siegebreaker for Lore Warden, take Heavy Armor Proficiency at level 2, and you get Combat Expertise for free at level 3. You'll still get Power Attack/Improved Overrun at level 3 because of your level 2 Fighter feat. I feel like Siegebreaker more aptly follows your goals of tanky steamroller, though. If you DO go Lore Warden, pick up the Gang Up feat at level 7- you are considered Flanking any time you have an ally next to the same opponent, removing the 'across from' requirement. Very good for Sneak Attacks.

That said, here's my example build:

Level 1 -- Sanctified Slayer 1

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 0(.75)
- Feat(s): Toughness (Trait), Intimidating Prowess

---

Level 2 -- Sanctified Slayer 1/Siegebreaker 1

- Class: Fighter (Lore Warden)
- BAB: 1(.75)

---

Level 3 -- Sanctified Slayer 1/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Siegebreaker
- BAB: 2(.75)
- Feat(s): Power Attack, Improved Overrun (Fighter)

---

Level 4 -- Sanctified Slayer 2/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Sanctified Slayer
- BAB: 3(.5)

---

Level 5 -- Sanctified Slayer 3/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 4(.25)
- Feat(s): Weapon Focus (Greatsword or whatever)

---

Level 6 -- Sanctified Slayer 4/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 5

---

Level 7 -- Sanctified Slayer 5/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 5(.75)
- Feat(s): Dodge OR Furious Focus

---

Level 8 -- Sanctified Slayer 6/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 6(.5)

---

Level 9 -- Sanctified Slayer 7/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 7(.25)
- Feat(s): Greater Overrun

---

Level 10 -- Sanctified Slayer 8/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 8
- Slayer Talent: Rogue Talent- Combat Trick
- Feat(s): Dazzling Display

---

Level 11 -- Sanctified Slayer 9/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 8(.75)
- Feat(s): Dodge OR Furious Focus

---

Level 12 -- Sanctified Slayer 10/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 9(.5)

---

Level 13 -- Sanctified Slayer 11/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 10(.25)
- Feat(s): Charge Through OR Persuasive

---

Level 14 -- Sanctified Slayer 12/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 11

---

Level 15 -- Sanctified Slayer 13/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 11(.75)
- Feat(s): Dreadful Carnage

---

Level 16 -- Sanctified Slayer 14/Siegebreaker 2

- Class: Inquisitor (Sanctified Slayer)
- BAB: 12